# How to send multiple HTTP requests with inertia

Tags: axios, inertiajs

Inertia is providing a very cool helper method, which is based on axios, I suggest, e.g.:

```
Inertia.post('/users', {
  name: 'John Doe',
  email: 'john.doe@example.com',
})
```

I haven't found it in the Inertia docs, so I ask here - is there a possibility to do multiple HTTP requests with Inertia like it's possible with axios?

```
// execute simultaneous requests 
axios.all([
  axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/mapbox'),
  axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/phantomjs')
])
.then(responseArr => {
  //this will be executed only when all requests are complete
  console.log('Date created: ', responseArr[0].data.created_at);
  console.log('Date created: ', responseArr[1].data.created_at);
});
```

Or should I just use axios to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware of; no, you cannot do multiple HTTP requests with Inertia like it's possible with axios. So, I would use axios to do that.

I interpret the docs as follows: Inertia [works](https://inertiajs.com/how-it-works) by intercepting clicks on the frontend, and making the visit by XHR. As such it is designed to do this one click at a time. The [`visit` method](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/blob/master/packages/inertia/src/inertia.js#L225) also shows that it makes this visit by calling axios with one url.

Also, since you're requesting plain JSON, the Inertia's author recommends to use XHR directly when dealing with plain JSON, because "an Inertia request must receive an Inertia response" ([source](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/issues/269#issuecomment-712366202)).